# Phonegap Memory Usage

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, memory-management

I am developing an application with `PhoneGap` for Android. I used SQLite and show data in an `HTML` grid that was created dynamically. My app includes some calculations. 
When I run my app the used memory of my device quickly increases (200 MB).
How can i reduce it?

a sample of my code in javascript:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
           tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
      }

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
  var st;
  for (i = 0; i < results.rows.lenght; i++) {
        var vText = document.getElementById("results");
        st += "<table><tr><td><label for='name'>Name:</label></td><td>"
              +"<input ype='text'  id='name'></input></td></tr>"
              +"<tr><td><label for='remarks'>Remarks:</label></td><td>"
              +"<lable  id='remarks'>"+results.rows.item[i].name+"</lable>"
              +"</td></tr></table>";
              vText.innerHTML = st;
       }
```

and html:

```
  <table id="results">
  </table>
```

every time i run this code it used 2MB space of memory(for 100 records)

Comment: put up your code.for to check where you are facing problems.

Comment: i can not reply(i am new user).i edited my post.

Comment: comment: you should **never** change the DOM inside a loop. Collect the HTML in some variable and write the innerHTML when the for loop is done. All at once. That might even help saving memory.